# How can a DMP be used for simulating physics?

Tags: motion-planning, algorithm, machine-learning

I read a paper from 2015, ["Structural bootstrapping - A novel, generative
mechanism for faster and more efficient acquisition of action-knowledge
"](http://h2t.anthropomatik.kit.edu/pdf/Woergoetter2015.pdf), which introduces a concept called, "Structural bootstrapping with semantic event chains and dynamic movement primitives," which confused me a little bit.

According to my knowledge a robotarm is controlled by a PDDL-like planner. The PDDL file is a "qualitative physics engine" which can predict future events. The paper says the "qualitative physics engine" consists of dynamic movement primitive (DMP) which are learned from motion capture data.

My question is: How can a DMP be used for simulating physics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know that the DMP method actually *simulates physics* as much as it *copies what it saw*, which was an actual, physical system. Note that "qualitative" means essentially "looks like", where "quantitative" means "numerically".

Qualitative physics simulations are those that *look like* real physics, but they are not. If I hold a dart in my hand and walk it across the room as though it were in the air, it would *look* roughly correct, but of course it would not be *numerically accurate*. So again, I think they're copying what they see and treating it as "good enough."

Answer (score 0):

The DMP method copies a trajectory instead of simulating physics. The guys in the paper store the recorded trajectory into a database as a matrix and reproduce it without modification on the robot. The event-chain matrix is on page 5 at [Learning the semantics of object-action relations by observation](http://upcommons.upc.edu/bitstream/handle/2117/14016/1244-Learning-the-semantics-of-object-action-relations-by-observation.pdf) But, in the paper [Execution of a Dual-Object (Pushing) Action with Semantic Event Chains](http://upcommons.upc.edu/bitstream/handle/2117/15177/1258-Execution-of-a-Dual-Object-(Pushing)-Action-with-Semantic-Event-Chains.pdf) is on page 4 a learning model used which is able to determine future result of an action (chapter "Defining Spatial Anchor Points"). My impression is, that a little bit of planning is in there. The author named it "model-sec" (Model Semantic Event Chain).

Comment: "The guys in the paper store the recorded trajectory into a database as a matrix and reproduce it without modification on the robot." I think they *do* attempt to modify it, based on evaluating what parameters are variable. See page 22 and the explanation of the stir/wipe sequence; I think it talks about the starting frame or key point being fixed by the end of the previous motion, leaving "only the adjustable parameters" or something similar available to the user to set.